# What does 'within the trade' mean?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean 'during the selling process' or 'in the industry?'

> Exotic pets pose a risk to human health and safety, particularly
> because some infectious diseases they carry are transmittable to
> humans. Ecological risks are also significant. Species loss due to the
> exotic pet trade can be so dramatic that experts have coined the term
> “empty forest syndrome” to describe some of these exporting zones. In
> importing regions, too, exotic pets can escape or be illegally
> released into non-native environments, where they may become invasive.
> The most famous case of this is the breeding population of Burmese
> pythons now established in the Florida Everglades. But the traded
> animals themselves arguably bear the risks of the exotic pet trade
> most profoundly. Pre-purchase mortality rates ***within the trade***
> are as high as 70 percent for reptiles and some birds, or 80 percent
> for wild-caught marine fish, with similar mortality rates persisting
> within the first year after purchase. Experts argue it is difficult if
> not impossible to provide adequate care for exotic pets.

[Humans and Animals: A Geography of Coexistence: A Geography of Coexistence](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=1xLGDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=Pre-purchase%20mortality%20rates%20within%20the%20trade&source=bl&ots=efTgz9cKyp&sig=ACfU3U0RjoiVQGkc8x-OhONaxOQznesqKA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia69y-mbDqAhXywosBHRGPAFUQ6AEwAXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=Pre-purchase%20mortality%20rates%20within%20the%20trade&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

It refers back to the previous sentence:

> … bear the risks of **the exotic pet trade** most profoundly.

In other words, the business of maintaining and selling exotic pets.

---

From [*trade*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trade):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> 1 a (2) : BUSINESS, MARKET
>             // novelties for the tourist *trade*

In that example sentence, it's not talking about exchanging (selling) tourists, but about the commerce that results from tourism.

Similarly, in the passage in the question, it's not talking about a specific exchange of animals (or trading money for animals). *Exotic pet* is being used adjectivally to describe the type of trade (business) in general.

---

Also, it's saying that in the exotic pet business, it's the exotic pets themselves who suffer the most:

> Experts argue it is difficult if not impossible to provide adequate care for exotic pets.

This isn't adequate care during a particular sale, but for the entire process of capturing them, holding them, and getting them into the hands of somebody else who must then also take care of them. (Such animals would have a much greater chance of survival if left in their natural wild state.)

Part of the previous sentence also indicates a much greater period of time than any simple exchange (emphasis mine):

> … with similar mortality rates persisting **within the first year after purchase**.